# Process Core Data in background thread after a delay

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data, alamofire

I have a table view to show a list fetched from API.

First I will store the API data to Core Data and on subsequent app launches I will try to update the list.

I need the update operation to be handled in a background thread. The update operation should be called after 5 seconds of launching that particular ViewController

```
func updateGlossary() {
    var GlobalMainQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_main_queue()
    }
    let delayInSeconds = 5.0
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(popTime, GlobalMainQueue) {
        self.showAlertMessage(message: "Updating Glossary")
        DataStore.GetToken({ (token, error) in
            //Got Token
           //Call the API for updated data and store it to core data
        })
    }
}
```

There are two problems in this;

1. The UI is getting blocked while update is going on
2. When I go back from the Controller before the update operation starts, still it will update from other controller (I think the issue is because of queuing)

I am using **Swift**, **Alamofire**, **Core Data**

Answer (score 0):

**For your first problem:-**

> The UI is getting blocked while update is going on

You should call the updateGlossary operation  in async way, it will not block the main thread:-

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
    [self performSelector:@"updateGlossary" withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0]
});
```

**For your Second problem:-**

> When I go back from the Controller before the update operation starts, still it will update from other controller (I think the issue is because of queuing)

Just stop the thread in the viewDidDisapper() method of your view controller

```
-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:FALSE];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateGlossary) object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The UI is getting blocked because you are making the API call on the mainQueue. Create a different queue and make the API call, later once you reach the main queue insert the API data into the Coredata.

I can see from your code that you are using `GlobalMainQueue` which is an alias for `dispatch_get_main_queue`, so your UI gets stuck.

**Solution as follows :**

```
 var GlobalBackgroundQueue: dispatch_queue_t
{
  return dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)
}

dispatch_after(popTime, GlobalBackgroundQueue) 
{ 
    //Make the API Call
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) 
    {
        //Insert Into CoreData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do CoreData operation using `dispatch_async`. `NSManagedObjectContext` per se is not thread safe and will cause unexpected behaviour. You might still use `dispatch_after` to call the block on the main thread.

Your code is fine except that your `getToken(:_)` is possibly happening on the main thread and/or your database operations are happening on the main thread hence blocking the UI.

You can modify your code like so:

```
func updateGlossary() {
    var GlobalMainQueue: dispatch_queue_t {
        return dispatch_get_main_queue()
    }
    let delayInSeconds = 5.0
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(popTime, GlobalMainQueue) {
        self.showAlertMessage(message: "Updating Glossary")
        DataStore.GetToken({ (token, error) in
            //Got Token
           //This will execute in the background
           self.callAPIWithToken(token, success: { (data) -> () in
              //Callback on the main thread
              self.privateManagedObjectContext.performBlock {
                //Will execute in its private thread
                //Insert to the database, save context
              }
           }) { (error) -> () in

           }
        })
    }
}
```

The `privateManagedObjectContext` is an instance of `NSManagedObjectContext` whose concurrency type is `.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and whose parent store is `.MainQueueConcurrencyType`. You use the `privateManagedObjectContext` to insert in the background and save your data. This approach is thread safe and will not block your UI.

[Here](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/) is a good article on multi-context core data systems.

**EDIT**
I don't suggest using `dispatch_after` if you want to cancel while moving away. Use `NSTimer` instead. Have it make the service call on the main thread after 5 seconds; invalidate it when you move away from the controller.

Comment: var appDel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!      This is my context and when I use this, getting an error NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can only use -performBlock: on an NSManagedObjectContext that was created with a queue.'

Comment: Correct. This is because the context that you are using is of type `.ConfinementQueueConcurrencyType`. Please read through the article that I have linked with the article. The approach will be clearer for you.

Comment: It works well, but how to cancel the queued task on moving away from the controller

Comment: Do you want to cancel the request or the database insertion?